# Sencha ExtJS: why do menus get attached to the Viewport instead of the instancing View?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs

Hey I'm new to ExtJS development and development in general. I'm still in college and I'm currently trying to build the UI for a Webapp made in ExtJS and I'm having a bit of a problem with menus and how they work. I am pretty sure I'm overlooking something and there has to be a simple way to do what I'm intending to do with menus.

To be specific I have 2 menus in my App and they both give me the same kind of problem... 
The first one uses code from this example: https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/examples/kitchensink/?modern#menus

it has a few fields that when changed then should update the main view... 
the problem here is that the menu gets attached to the Viewport

```
this.topMenu = Ext.Viewport.setMenu(this.getMenuCfg('top'), {
            side: 'top'
        });
```

which sets the scope of the fields' listeners that are inside the menu to the viewport instead of to the instancing views' controller which then makes it hard to get to the actual components I was looking for inside my main view or even loading stores from the viewmodel attached to my main view.

in fact I had to reverse engineer it with a debugger to then find this cryptic way to my store:

```
var me = this,
    vm = me.getViewModel().children["generated-cryptic-name-of-my-model-1"],
    myStore = vm.getStore('MyStore');
```

and of course the problem also works the other way around...
inside methods fired from my main views' controller I won't be able to find the references of the components inside the menu with

```
this.lookupReference('reference')
```

instead I had to again find a rather unintuitive a way to my components by giving them an ID. Again I only found this by using a debugger... it looks like this:

```
var me = this,
    menuItems = me.topMenu.getActiveItem().getItems(),
    fieldset = menuItems.getByKey('fldSet'),
    myField = fieldset.getItems().getByKey('myField');
```

because I was only using 1 menu in my entire App at first I saw it as sort of technical debt and I didnt really look into it any further because I found a workaround.

But now I added another Menu, this time to the split section of a SplitButton, as shown in the Docs(https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.7.0/modern/Ext.SplitButton.html)

and again the menu gets attached to the viewport instead of the instancing view, which makes the handler functions fire at the viewportcontroller and takes the ability to find the references of my components inside the instancing views with `this.lookupReference('reference')`.

I can make the handlers fire at the right controller by setting a controller config for the menu when instancing, but I haven't found an easy way of getting my components references and it is really bugging me at this point...

I would love to hear your suggestions, cheers ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably help to know which views, viewcontrollers and viewmodels there are. The code `vm = me.getViewModel().children["generated-cryptic-name-of-my-model-1"]` makes me suspect there are more viewmodels and viewcontrollers involved, and it would help to know their relations. I wouldn't be surprised if the menus are not the problem at all...

Comment: this is what confuses me so much, there should only be my one and only ViewModel and also only one ViewController (I haven't defined any other) the view my View also only has parents. I have a base View where unspecific configs like controller and Viewmodel are made and then I have an extending class that contains the actual components and stuff... I did this, so I would be able to have different views for desktop or tablet version of my app that would all extend the base view

Comment: What I probably would do is setup an afterrender function in the viewcontroller and log what the connected view is (this.getView()). This view should contain your menu items. Same goes for the viewmodel with this.getViewModel(). Just to make sure. I haven't got much exxperience with modern, but in classic extjs a window (if you are using moadl windows) only uses the original view and viewmodel if it is added like this : this.getView().add(theWindow).show();